# What is the "Noble Truth"?

Tags: untagged

I read the following on the internet:

> what ever deed opposing and harming the Noble truth.

What exactly is the Noble Truth?

How is the Noble Truth opposed & harmed?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To quote Sutta accurately & succinctly:

> Noble = noble, without effluents, transcendent (MN 117)

> Transcendent = transcendent, connected with emptiness (SN 20.7)

> Emptiness = empty of a self or of anything pertaining to a self (SN 35.85; MN 43)

> Emptiness = empty of the canker of sense-pleasures, becoming & ignorance (MN 121)

Noble = without effluents, transcendent, empty of a self

Comment: I marked this answer down because it appears you only asked the question as an excuse to proselytise your views. Disingenuous and tiresome behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Telling of what is subject to decay, not real, no refuge, it's real, a refuge. Dwelling in householder-equanimity and telling "this is sunnata", this is also thief and harm. Crying around "oh, my health, oh my house, oh my burdens", while claiming to be Noble, this is also one of the bigfest thieves.

Denying goodness, thinking "i can, could", using the parents gifts to harm them, also this is haming the truth.

Telling that actions have no effects for householders: also this is harming the truth.

Telling there is no next world, no Devas, no Hell: this is also harming the truth.

Telling that beings come from nothing and go to nothing: this is also harming the truth.

Declaring liberation as here and now: this is also harming the truth.

Saying liberation can be attained without leaving house/standn this is also harming the truth.

Caught in wrong view, harming the truth, denying obligations, the offender, the one who opposes the Gems, headed by the Sublime Buddha, is destinated right here and now, to fall into pain, finds no more way out, slayed by this evil deeds and nobody can help him, make him stop stupidity, again and again, good poor householder.

The list of opposing and harming the four Noble truth would be long, as long as poor good householders ongoing wandering on.

Comment: thank u for your answer however i  recommend u read MN 117 https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html which says teachings about goodness, mother, father, etc, are connected to asava (defilement) & upadhi (attachment; acquisition) therefore are not "Noble"

Comment: Dhamma Dhatu for many years now has been posting Noble Dhamma on this forum. Please do not be like Ananda, to whom the Lord Buddha warned in MN 122: "So, Ānanda, treat me as a friend, not as an enemy. That will be for your lasting welfare and happiness".

Answer (score 0):

Noble Truth=The truth to get out of all suffering by the completely developed person.

Suffering truth is every arising and vanishing stuffs such as electron-particles and minds.

Suffering's origin truth is every craving and clinging of both wrong and right suffering.

Suffering's cessation(suffering's opposite) truth is the cessation of the suffering and the suffering origin. This is unable  to imagine because it will appear  only to the one who can cease the suffering's origin completely.

Suffering's cessation operations truth is the practices to cease the suffering and suffering origin truth.